# Check if Eigen Decomposition has been computed

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I check to see if `compute` has previously been run on an `Eigen::Solver`? There is a protected member variable `m_isInitialized` in **Eigen/src/EigenValues/EigenSolver.h** but I don't see a getter for it.

The code below shows an example of how you would create a matrix and compute the eigen decomposition on it.  In my case, I have a reference/pointer to an `Eigen::Solver` so I don't know if it's been previously computed or not.

- [EigenSolver.h docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html)
- [EigenSolver.h source](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h)

```
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues> 
...
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> matrix;
matrix << 1,2,3,
          1,2,3,
          1,2,3;

Eigen::Solver<double, 3, 3> eigen_decomp;

// This next line is the compute I'm referring to
eigen_decomp.compute(matrix, /* computeEigenvectors = */ true);
std::cout << eigen_decomp.eigenValues() << "\n";
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is. You have to keep a separate flag yourself.

Comment: Yes, that was not considered a useful use-case when the API was designed, although it should not be hard to implement. You can make a feature-request for that (maybe the `info()` method could return a new `NotInitialized` flag or something.)

Comment: @chtz, the first line of the `info()` function calls `eigen_assert(m_isInitialized && "EigenSolver is not initialized.");`

Comment: Yes, as I said, that would require changing Eigen (i.e., making a feature request). If you don't want to do that, you can inherit from `Eigen::EigenSolver` and create a new access method -- `m_isInitialized` is only protected, IIRC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, assuming you don't want to wait for a feature request for Eigen, the easiest wokaround is `std::optional`

```
std::optional<Eigen::Solver<double, 3, 3>> eigen_decomp;
if(! eigen_decomp)
    eigen_decom.emplace(matrix, /* computeEigenvectors = */ true);
std::cout << eigen_decomp->eigenValues() << "\n";
```